# Escaping a single quote in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

The recommendations I have come across advise that single quotes in SQL Server should be escaped using two single quotes. Thus [Ravi's becomes Ravi''s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716428/can-we-escape-single-quote-in-sql-server-query).

Another alternative is to use parameters.

In most of the examples I have seen the words usually have only one quote. Most times it works but I have been unable to make it work while creating a database login.

```
CREATE LOGIN Ng''ang''a  WITH PASSWORD  'Ng''0ng''0'
```

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: I think your missing quotes around your user name.

Comment: create login [Ng'ang'a] Surround your login name with square brackets.

Comment: Try: CREATE LOGIN [Ng'ang'a] WITH PASSWORD = 'Ng''0ng''0'

Comment: Why does your login need to have single quotes in it? While it is certainly allowed to do that, I think you should question it as you're going to run into other problems after you've created it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand can you imagine escaping the connection string?

Answer (score 5):

The user name is an ID/QUOTED ID that should be enclosed in `double quotes` or `square brackets` while the password is a regular string where single quotes need to be doubled. The correct syntax would in other words be;

```
CREATE LOGIN "Ng'ang'a" WITH PASSWORD='Ng''0ng''0'
```

or

```
CREATE LOGIN [Ng'ang'a] WITH PASSWORD='Ng''0ng''0'
```

Comment: double quotes will only work if `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `ON` but +1 for explaining why the user name is different than the password

Comment: @Conrad Double quotes are also really hard to read and confuse new users who aren't sure if they're strings or identifiers. But creating a login with an apostrophe is not exactly a good idea in the first place.

Comment: @ConradFrix Did not know that since it seems to be turned on by default, thanks!

Comment: @AaronBertrand The user wants to use his actual name which has single quotes.

Comment: @CallMeKags I didn't say there isn't a reason, I just said it isn't a good idea. As I suggested above, this is not the last time you're going to have an issue with this.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  Thanks CREATE LOGIN [Ng'ang'a] WITH PASSWORD='Ng''0ng''0' works fine and the user is now happy.

Comment: @CallMeKags I think you should accept the answer if it satisfied you so that other users will identify the solution.