# Escaping a single quote in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL server 2005 and using the northwind database. I need the supplier id of  Grandma Kelly's Homestead and I used this query:

```
select supplierid from suppliers
where companyname ='Grandma Kelly''s'' Homestead'
```

I checked the link [Escaping a single quote in SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14090/escaping-a-single-quote-in-sql-server), but I can't find an answer.

I used the two single quotes but it didn't work since the query is executing but it doesn't return a value.

How can I escape the single quote and retrieve the value? I would also like to know how to insert the values into the table having quotes

Comment: Should it be = 'Grandma Kelly''s Homestead'? No apostrophe(s) after the "s" (which don't make sense in English anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just meant:

```
select supplierid from dbo.suppliers
where companyname ='Grandma Kelly''s Homestead';
```

(In other words, there was only one apostrophe to replace.)